# Locally test AWS Lambda container with .NET 5 web api and Lambda RIE

Tags: testing, aws-lambda, containers, .net-5

I'm following the instructions to locally test lambda container https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html

but I am unable to do so.

I've created a sample project to reproduce it https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/lambda-dotnet5-webapi (see the README for step by step on its generation)

Basically I am using an Amazon dotnet template that generates an AWS Lambda function as a .NET 5 web api using containers.

It's all good with the project. The Dockerfile is described as

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/dotnet:5.0
WORKDIR /var/task
COPY "bin/Release/net5.0/publish"  .
```

Now I want to test it locally using the **Amazon Lambda Runtime Interface Emulator** (RIE) and these are the steps I follow:

1. Build project with `dotnet build -c Release`
2. Publish artifacts with `dotnet publish -c Release`
3. Build docker image with `docker build -t lambda-dotnet .`
4. Download the RIE with

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.aws-lambda-rie && curl -Lo ~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/releases/latest/download/aws-lambda-rie && chmod +x ~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie
   ```

   I can see the emulator downloaded properly

   ```
   ls -la ~/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie
   -rw-r--r-- 1 diego.martin 1049089 8155136 Feb 22 14:32 /c/Users/diego.martin/.aws-lambda-rie/aws-lambda-rie
   ```
5. Run the emulator passing the lambda image

   ```
   docker run -d -v ~/.aws-lambda-rie:/aws-lambda -p 9000:8080 --entrypoint /aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie lambda-dotnet:latest
   ```

Here is when I get the error

```
12997dddc6e50aca3020527be30a1479eee9ceef412ab5009b99e9eb8cf1fa67
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "C:/Users/diego.martin/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie": stat C:/Users/diego.martin/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/aws-lambda/aws-lambda-rie: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

What am I missing? I am not specifying any entrypoint because I don't have any.

PS: The last step would be to send some lambda event to my container's function with

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}'
```

Comment: I created an issue https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-runtime-interface-emulator/issues/24 to ask for more documentation for newbies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda docker images for dotnet already include the RIE, so it's enough with the following (see repo with further details):

To build image

```
docker build -t lambda-dotnet:latest .
```

To run it

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 lambda-dotnet "LambdaDotNet5::LambdaDotNet5.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync"
```

And then to test it, I can use CURL from a different terminal

```
curl -vX POST http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -d @test_request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

and in the `test_request.json` file I can have the json for the event I want to send to the lambda.

Comment: Or for windows `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations -Headers @{ "Content-Type" = "application/json" } -Method Post -InFile test_request.json`